# XLST/XML: pulling different nodes while comparing attribute to WITHOUT using <xsl:for-each>

Tags: xml, xslt, nodes

I apologize if this has been asked, but I'm having a heck of a time trying to find the specific example I am looking for.

I am trying to search through XML nodes from an XML document I have. Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<courses>
  <course number="341" credits="4.0">
    <title>Data Structures</title>
    <section number="01" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>15</enrollment>
      <room>EA244</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
    <section number="02" delivery="Online">
      <enrollment>10</enrollment>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
        <last>Lin</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
    <section number="03" delivery="Classroom">
      <enrollment>12</enrollment>
      <room>SH102</room>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mark</first>
        <last>Funk</last>
      </instructor>
    </section>
  </course>

</courses>
```

The XSLT I'm working with is ok, it is pulling all the attributes and elements I need for the MOST part, BUT there's a couple major flaws:
1)I need to pull ONLY those elements with delivery attributes "Classroom" and I'm getting child elements for EVERY course since the boolean value returns true and then pulls down EVERY child element of "course"

2)I'm unable to sort according to enrollment, I think because of this same issue.  I am not able to use for-each, and I've tried looking and understanding recursion in XML, but when I try using recursive calls I get "null" when I test out my XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <classes>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="courses/course/section" />  
  <xsl:apply-templates select="courses/course" />
</classes>
</xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="section">
   <xsl:attribute name="count">
     <xsl:value-of select="count(//section[@delivery='Classroom'])" />
   </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="course">
 <class>
  <xsl:if test="section[@delivery='Classroom']">
    <xsl:attribute name="credits">
      <xsl:value-of select="@credits" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="room">
      <xsl:value-of select="section/room" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <enrollment><xsl:value-of select="section/enrollment" /></enrollment>
    <instructor><xsl:copy-of select="section/instructor" /></instructor>
    <number><xsl:value-of select="@number" /></number>
    <title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></title>
    </xsl:if>
   </class>
  </xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can/is willing to help.

Edit: This is my current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classes count="4">
  <class credits="4.0" room="EA244">
    <enrollment>15</enrollment>
    <instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
        <last>Lin</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mark</first>
        <last>Funk</last>
      </instructor>
    </instructor>
    <number>341</number>
    <title>Data Structures</title>
  </class>
  <class credits="4.0" room="AT102">
    <enrollment>9</enrollment>
    <instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
        <last>Lin</last>
      </instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Mingrui</first>
        <last>Zhang</last>
      </instructor>
    </instructor>
    <number>368</number>
    <title>Introduction to Bioinformatics</title>
  </class>
  <class/>
  <class credits="3.0" room="ST108">
    <enrollment>26</enrollment>
    <instructor>
      <instructor>
        <first>Nicole</first>
        <last>Anderson</last>
      </instructor>
    </instructor>
    <number>385</number>
    <title>Applied Database Management Systems</title>
  </class>
  <class/>
</classes>
```

So the problem I'm having is that I need each course (from the first XML file) to show class credits, number, and ONLY the child nodes of the sections that are delivered in a "Classroom".  It works fine with most of the cases since there is only one section for all courses EXCEPT the first one which has three sections, two of which are @delivery="Classroom".  That one is giving me ALL child elements of the course

Edit 2: the output should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classes count="4">
  <class credits="4.0" room="AT102">
    <number>368</number>
    <title>Introduction to Bioinformatics</title>
    <enrollment>9</enrollment>
    <instructor>
      <first>Chi-Cheng</first>
      <last>Lin</last>
    </instructor>
    <instructor>
      <first>Mingrui</first>
      <last>Zhang</last>
    </instructor>
  </class>
  <class credits="4.0" room="SH102">
    <number>341</number>
    <title>Data Structures</title>
    <enrollment>12</enrollment>
    <instructor>
      <first>Mark</first>
      <last>Funk</last>
    </instructor>
  </class>
  <class credits="4.0" room="EA244">
    <number>341</number>
    <title>Data Structures</title>
    <enrollment>15</enrollment>
    <instructor>
      <first>Nicole</first>
      <last>Anderson</last>
    </instructor>
  </class>
  <class credits="3.0" room="ST108">
    <number>385</number>
    <title>Applied Database Management Systems</title>
    <enrollment>26</enrollment>
    <instructor>
      <first>Nicole</first>
      <last>Anderson</last>
    </instructor>
  </class>
</classes>
```

I believe the reason that the second classroom isn't showing up (and making a new class element) is because I am getting a boolean value of true the first time I pull nodes because section[@delivery='Classroom'] is true in the first instance.  So it's just pulling all the nodes right away.  Also, this same issue is causing my sort to give me an incorrect output.

Comment: You are much more likely to get help if you [edit] your post to include the desired output XML.

Comment: I will get right on that

Comment: Can you also show the result you want? It is not clear to me whether you want to map each input `course` element to an output `class` and then nest the `section` content or whether you want to map each `course/section[@delivery = 'classroom']` to a `class`. As for sorting and using `apply-templates`, you can do that with e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="section"><xsl:sort select="enrollment"/></xsl:apply-templates/>`.

Comment: Please edit your input too and show us the missing classes that appear in your output. -- Note also that room `SH102` is missing from your output - why is that?

Comment: I will edit the input.  Martin-I want to map each course/section[@delivery='Classroom'] to a class.

Comment: Your output still does not match your input. There are 4 classes in your output, but the input has only 2 sections that take place in a classroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `class` for each `section` that is delivered in a classroom, then you should do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/courses">
    <xsl:variable name="classroom-sections" select="course/section[@delivery='Classroom']" />
    <classes count="{count($classroom-sections)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$classroom-sections" />  
    </classes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
    <class credits="{../@credits}" room="{room}">
        <number>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@number" />
        </number>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../title | enrollment | instructor"/>
    </class>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. I don't know why you stress in your title that you want to do this "WITHOUT using `<xsl:for-each>`". The `xsl:for-each` instruction is an integral part of the XSLT language and could be used here just as well, with no ill effects whatsoever.

Comment: This worked marvelously.   So I see that you've made a variable for classroom-sections, which I had tried in a previous iteration, but I know I didn't set the XPath as "course/section[@delivery='Classroom']"  Thank you so very much. This makes a lot of sense.  I'm new to XML and understand Java better, functional programming is new to me.  This is a great building block.